# Replace integers from specific words from a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, java

I am having a file xyz.sh

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx3072M"  
RESOLVED_HEAP_SIZE="2048M"  
RESOLVED_OFF_HEAP_SIZE="256M"
```

Expected - I want to replace `-Xmx3072M` with `-Xmx4096M` but is not compulsory that value of `JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx3072"` will always be same it can be `-Xmx1234` or `-Xmx5120`.

Comment: Is there a reason to do this programmatically and not with an editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
sed -e '/JAVA_OPTS/ s/".*"/"-Xmx4096M"/' test453

JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx4096M"  
RESOLVED_HEAP_SIZE="2048M"  
RESOLVED_OFF_HEAP_SIZE="256M"
```

- search for the match `JAVA_OPTS`
- `".*"` will replace whatever pattern between double quotes with `"-Xmx4096M"`
- if you want to edit the file, replace `-e` with `-i`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/JAVA_OPTS/s/-Xmx[[:digit:]]\{1,\}[kKmMgG]\{0,1\}/-Xmx4G/'
```

Would replace `-Xmx` followed by one or more decimal digits followed by an optional k/K/m/M/g/G suffix with `-Xmx4G` on lines that contain `JAVA_OPTS` without touching any other eventual java option.